# Cypress.exec call external script and set an environmental variable

Tags: cypress

I want to call an external script from a Cypress test, do some stuff and export/set an environmental variable with I can then access from a test. Below is what I have so far.

```
describe("Test to create a capability", function () {
    before(() => {
        cy.exec("node set-env.js");
        cy.log(Cypress.env("key"));
    });
});

// in set-env.js
const Cypress = require('cypress');
const key = somefunction('test');
console.log(key);
// process.env('key', key); - this doesn't work
// Cypress.env('key', key); - this doesn't work
```

Not sure what I need to be able to run a Node script before my Cypress tests run and export an environmental variable or return a value that I can use in the tests.

Comment: Is this useful to you https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Setting

Comment: From the link that @AndrewBibby provided, you'll probably want to look at "Option #5: Plugins". Plugins allow you to interact with node directly. From there, you can return the values you want (or hopefully get the environment variables somehow)..